Sets with Cantor-Bendixson rank $\omega$ and $\omega+1$ and their difference
I am struggling to internalize how do we construct sets with CB ranks $\omega$ and $\omega+1$. I can imagine one of them but then I don't understand the other. Here's what I mean.
I know how to construct a set with rank n for some natural. For rank 1 take $\{0\}$. Then add the sequence $1/n$ to get rank 2, then add sequences to all previous isolated points and so on recursively.
What will I get if I extend this for every natural? My understanding is that I will get the set with rank $\omega$? As the empty set should come out in the end. If that is so then how would I construct one with $\omega + 1$? I need some point to survive in order to do it?
If my understanding is wrong and actually the result of $\omega$ derivations is not empty but rather $\{0\}$ then that will be the set with $\omega + 1$ rank. But then how do I get the one with just $\omega$ rank?
I'm missing some intuition and if you could please answer from a set theory perspective rather than a topology one that will be greatly appreciated.

This MSE answer should be helpful in getting fairly straightforward examples for what you want, and for much larger ordinals (but not especially large; starts getting descriptively difficult much past ${\omega}^{\omega}).$

To get to $\omega + 1$ you can place copies of the set of rank $\omega$ that you already constructed in the intervals $(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n})$ and add $0$.

That's what I'm thinking as well but since the set with rank  ω still boils down to the empty set I don't understand how the numbers of the form 1/n will survive after infinite steps?

@user9855939 Yes, the sets of rank $\omega$ will boil down to the empty set after $\omega$ many steps. But then you are still left over with $0$. So you need one extra step to remove $0$.

But isn't the derivative of 0 part of the w steps we take? If it's not then aren't the total steps w + 1? Taking the w derivative is like taking the intersection of all steps right? So we will always get empty set in the end? I struggle to realize how the intersection will contain anything if in the end it all boils down to empty set.

@user9855939 $0$ is not removed in any finite step because at each finite step there is something left in each of the copies of the rank $\omega$ set, so $0$ stays non-isolated.

Ok so then isn't this w + 1 steps? If 0 stays non-isolated after w steps then after 1 more we get to the empty set. Why do we need the construction in your first comment for w+1 if we have 0 left out?

@user9855939 Yes, I gave an example of a set of CB rank $\omega +1$. Isn't this what you asked for? I don't understand the rest of your comment.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Here is a general recursive procedure for constructing a set $A_\alpha$ of CB rank $\alpha$ for any countable ordinal $\alpha$:
First we may simply let $A_0 = \emptyset$ and $A_1 = \{0\}$, as you also note.
Then suppose that we already have constructed $A_\beta$ for each $\beta< \alpha$.
If $\alpha$ is of the form $\beta +1$ (i.e. a successor ordinal) we let $A_\alpha$ be the set that is obtained by placing a homeomorphic copy of $A_{\beta}$ in the interval $(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n})$ for each $n$ (e.g. by stretching and translating) and by adding the element $0$.
Otherwise, if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal let $(\beta_n)$ be a cofinal sequence in $\alpha$. Then we let $A_\alpha$ be the set that is obtained by placing a homeomorphic copy of $A_{\beta_n}$ in the interval $(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n})$ for each $n$.
Inductively you can prove now that $A_\alpha$ has rank exactly $\alpha$
